# Selecting a date between two dates while also accounting for separate time field

Tags: python, postgresql

I have a date and a time field in Postgresql. I am reading it in python and need to sort out things on certain days past certain times.

The steps would basically be like this:

1. Select * from x where date > monthdayyear
2. In that subset, select only those that are > time given for that date
3. AND date2 must be < monthdayyear2 AND time2 must be less than time2 given on that date

I know there are definitely some python ways I could do this, by iterating through results and et cetera. I'm wondering if there is a better way than brute forcing this? I would rather not run multiple queries or have to sort out a lot of extra results in the fetchall() if possible.

Comment: Pg version? Sample data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I've understood your design, this is really a schema design issue. Instead of:

```
CREATE TABLE sometable (
    date1 date,
    time1 time,
    date2 date,
    time2 time
);
```

you generally want:

```
CREATE TABLE sometable (
    timestamp1 timestamp with time zone,
    timestamp2 timestamp with time zone
);
```

if you want the timestamp converted automatically to UTC and back to the client's `TimeZone`, or `timestamp without time zone` if you want to store the raw timestamp without timezone conversion.

If an inclusive test is OK, you can write:

```
SELECT ...
FROM sometable 
WHERE '2012-01-01 11:15 +0800' BETWEEN timestamp1 AND timestamp2;
```

If you cannot amend your schema, your best bet is something like this:

```
SELECT ...
FROM sometable
WHERE '2012-01-01 11:15 +0800' BETWEEN (date1 + time1) AND (date2 + time2);
```

This may have some unexpected quirks when it comes to clients in multiple time zones; you may land up needing to look at the `AT TIME ZONE` operator.

If you need an exclusive test on one side an/or the other, you can't use `BETWEEN` since it's an `a <= x <= b` operator. Instead write:

```
SELECT ...
FROM sometable
WHERE '2012-01-01 11:15 +0800' > (date1 + time1)
  AND '2012-01-01 11:15 +0800' < (date2 + time2);
```

### Automating the schema change

Automating a schema change is possible.

You want to query `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` or `pg_catalog.pg_class` and `pg_catalog.pg_attribute` for tables that have pairs of `date` and `time` columns, then generate sets of `ALTER TABLE` commands to unify them.

Determining what a "pair" is is quite application specific; if you've used a consistent naming scheme it should be easy to do with `LIKE` or `~` operators and/or `regexp_matches`. You want to produce a set of `(tablename, datecolumnname, timecolumnname)` tuples.

Once you have that, you can for each `(tablename, datecolumnname, timecolumnname)` tuple produce the following `ALTER TABLE` statements, which *must* be run in a transaction to be safe, and should be tested before use on any data you care about, and where the entries in `[brackets]` are substitutions:

```
BEGIN;
ALTER TABLE [tablename] ADD COLUMN [timestampcolumnname] TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE;
--
-- WARNING: This part can lose data; if one of the columns is null and the other one isn't
-- the result is null. You should've had a CHECK constraint preventing that, but probably
-- didn't. You might need to special case that; the `coalesce` and `nullif` functions and
-- the `CASE` clause might be useful if so.
--
UPDATE [tablename] SET [timestampcolumnname] = ([datecolumnname] + [timecolumnname]);
ALTER TABLE [tablename] DROP COLUMN [datecolumnname];
ALTER TABLE [tablename] DROP COLUMN [timecolumnname];
-- Finally, if the originals were NOT NULL:
ALTER TABLE [tablename] ALTER COLUMN [timestampcolumnname] SET NOT NULL;
```

then check the results and `COMMIT` if happy. Be aware that an exclusive lock is taken on the table from the first `ALTER` so nothing else can use the table until you `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK`.

If you're on a vaguely modern PostgreSQL you can generate the SQL with [the `format` function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html); on older versions you can use string concatenation (`||`) and the `quote_literal` function. Example:

Given the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE sometable(date1 date not null, time1 time not null, date2 date not null, time2 time not null);
INSERT INTO sometable(date1,time1,date2,time2) VALUES
('2012-01-01','11:15','2012-02-03','04:00');

CREATE TABLE othertable(somedate date, sometime time);
INSERT INTO othertable(somedate, sometime) VALUES
(NULL, NULL),
(NULL, '11:15'),
('2012-03-08',NULL),
('2014-09-18','23:12');
```

Here's a query that generates the input data set. Note that it relies on the naming convention that matching column pairs always have a common name once any `date` or `time` word is removed from the column. You could instead use adjacency by testing for `c1.attnum + 1 = c2.attnum`.

```
BEGIN;

WITH 
-- Create set of each date/time column along with its table name, oids, and not null flag
cols AS (
    select attrelid, relname, attname, typname, atttypid, attnotnull 
    from pg_attribute 
    inner join pg_class on pg_attribute.attrelid = pg_class.oid 
    inner join pg_type on pg_attribute.atttypid = pg_type.oid 
    where NOT attisdropped AND atttypid IN ('date'::regtype, 'time'::regtype)
),
-- Self join the time and date column set, filtering the left side for only dates and
-- the right side for only times, producing two distinct sets. Then filter for entries
-- where the names are the same after replacing any appearance of the word `date` or
-- `time`.
tableinfo (tablename, datecolumnname, timecolumnname, nonnull, hastimezone) AS (
    SELECT 
        c1.relname, c1.attname, c2.attname, 
        c1.attnotnull AND c2.attnotnull AS nonnull, 
        't'::boolean AS withtimezone
    FROM cols c1 
    INNER JOIN cols c2 ON (
        c1.atttypid = 'date'::regtype 
        AND c2.atttypid = 'time'::regtype 
        AND c1.attrelid = c2.attrelid
        -- Match column pairs; I used name matching, you might use adjancency:
        AND replace(c1.attname,'date','') = replace(c2.attname,'time','')
    )
)
-- Finally, format the results into a series of ALTER TABLE statements.
SELECT format($$
    ALTER TABLE %1$I ADD COLUMN %4$I TIMESTAMP %5$s;
    UPDATE %1$I SET %4$I = (%2$I + %3$I);
    ALTER TABLE %1$I DROP COLUMN %2$I;
    ALTER TABLE %1$I DROP COLUMN %3$I;
$$ || 
    -- Append a clause to make the column NOT NULL now that it's populated, only
    -- if the original date or time were NOT NULL:
    CASE 
       WHEN nonnull
       THEN '    ALTER TABLE %1$I ALTER COLUMN %4$I SET NOT NULL;'
       ELSE ''
    END,

    -- Now the format arguments
    tablename,           -- 1
    datecolumnname,      -- 2
    timecolumnname,      -- 3
    -- You'd use a better column name generator than this simple example:
    datecolumnname||'_'||timecolumnname,  -- 4
    CASE 
       WHEN hastimezone THEN 'WITH TIME ZONE' 
       ELSE 'WITHOUT TIME ZONE' 
    END                  -- 5
)
FROM tableinfo;
```

You can read the results and send them as SQL commands in a second session, or if you want to get fancy you can write a fairly simple PL/PgSQL function that `LOOP`s over the results and `EXECUTE`s each one. The query produces output like:

```
    ALTER TABLE sometable ADD COLUMN date1_time1 TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE;
    UPDATE sometable SET date1_time1 = (date1 + time1);
    ALTER TABLE sometable DROP COLUMN date1;
    ALTER TABLE sometable DROP COLUMN time1;
    ALTER TABLE sometable ALTER COLUMN date1_time1 SET NOT NULL;

    ALTER TABLE sometable ADD COLUMN date2_time2 TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE;
    UPDATE sometable SET date2_time2 = (date2 + time2);
    ALTER TABLE sometable DROP COLUMN date2;
    ALTER TABLE sometable DROP COLUMN time2;
    ALTER TABLE sometable ALTER COLUMN date2_time2 SET NOT NULL;

    ALTER TABLE othertable ADD COLUMN somedate_sometime TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE;
    UPDATE othertable SET somedate_sometime = (somedate + sometime);
    ALTER TABLE othertable DROP COLUMN somedate;
    ALTER TABLE othertable DROP COLUMN sometime;
```

I don't know if there's any useful way to work out on a per-column basis whether you want `WITH TIME ZONE` or `WITHOUT TIME ZONE`. It's likely you'll land up just doing it hardcoded, in which case you can just remove that column. I put it in there in case there's a good way to figure it out in your application.

If you have cases where the time can be null but the date non-null or vice versa, you will need to wrap the date and time in an expression that decide what result to return when null. The `nullif` and `coalesce` functions are useful for this, as is `CASE`. Remember that adding a null and a non-null value produces a null result so you may not need to do anything special.

If you use schemas you may need to further refine the query to use %I substitution of schema name prefixes to disambiguate. If you don't use schemas (if you don't know what one is, you don't) then this doesn't matter.

Consider adding `CHECK` constraints enforcing that `time1` is less than or equal to `time2` where it makes sense in your application once you've done this. Also look at exclusion constraints in the documentation.

Comment: Hey, I agree it is a schema thing. Is there a good way for me to automate going through the table and changing it all to timestamps in python?

Comment: @user1610719 It's certainly possible; you could even generate the required commands with an SQL query. See edited answer.

Comment: @user1610719 Revised with format() function to generate the `ALTER` statements, just for kicks.

Comment: @user1610719 Since it's kind of fun, wrote the query against the catalog to find pairs of `date` and `time` columns and produce suitable tuples for input into the first query. It's a monster query, but it works

Comment: Haha, well they all had dates and times, and I just used Python to loop through a fetchall() in psycopg2, took the results and updated the row with datetime.datetime.combine() in a new column

Comment: @user1610719 Yeah, if you only had a couple of tables that's the obvious way to go. I got the impression from your question that you had too many different uses of this date+time pattern for it to be easy to just correct each table's DDL manually.