# how to speed up max() query

Tags: sql, postgresql

In PostgreSql 8.4 query

```
explain analyze SELECT 
    max( kuupaev||kellaaeg ) as res
  from ALGSA 
  where laonr=1 and kuupaev <='9999-12-31' and 
     kuupaev||kellaaeg <= '9999-12-3123 59'
```

Takes 3 seconds to run:

```
"Aggregate  (cost=3164.49..3164.50 rows=1 width=10) (actual time=2714.269..2714.270 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  ->  Seq Scan on algsa  (cost=0.00..3110.04 rows=21778 width=10) (actual time=0.105..1418.743 rows=70708 loops=1)"
"        Filter: ((kuupaev <= '9999-12-31'::date) AND (laonr = 1::numeric) AND ((kuupaev || (kellaaeg)::text) <= '9999-12-3123 59'::text))"
"Total runtime: 2714.363 ms"
```

How to speed it up in PostgreSQL 8.4.4 ?
Table structure is below.
algsa table has index on kuupaev maybe this can be used?
Or is it possible to change query to add some other index to make it fast. Exising columns in table cannot changed.

```
CREATE TABLE firma1.algsa
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  laonr numeric(2,0),
  kuupaev date NOT NULL,
  kellaaeg character(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''::bpchar,
  ... other columns
  CONSTRAINT algsa_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT algsa_id_check CHECK (id > 0)
)
);

CREATE INDEX algsa_kuupaev_idx  ON firma1.algsa  USING btree  (kuupaev);
```

**Update**

Tried `analyze verbose firma1.algsa;`

```
INFO:  analyzing "firma1.algsa"
INFO:  "algsa": scanned 1640 of 1640 pages, containing 70708 live rows and 13 dead rows; 30000 rows in sample, 70708 estimated total rows
Query returned successfully with no result in 1185 ms.
```

but query run time was still 2.7 seconds.

Why there are `30000 rows in sample`  . Isn't it too much, should this decreased?

Comment: Thank you. Upgrading server is lot of work. Maybe there is some way in 8.4 , please? If not, upgrade is possible.

Comment: Despite that, +1 for including table structure, full Pg version, and `explain analyze`. Thanks. Saves us the time of trying to figure out why it's not behaving when the answer is probably "too old, doesn't support that". You could try `ANALYZE`ing the tables, but I suspect 8.4 just doesn't have the smarts.

Comment: Hmm, looks like `min` and `max` were index-capable by the time 8.4 rolled around, might not be a simple old-version problem.

Comment: Thank you. I tried analyze and updated question about sample rows issue. This is Windows 2003 server. I can upgrade Postgres in some evening if this helps. Customer wrote that this query was fast earlier, PostgreSql version was same earlier. I upgraded it from something like 8.1 number of years ago.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was a known issue in old versions of PostgreSQL - but it looks like it might've been resolved by 8.4; in fact, the [docs for 8.0](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/functions-aggregate.html) have the caveat but the [docs for 8.1](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-aggregate.html) do not.

So you don't need to upgrade major versions for this reason, at least. You should however upgrade to the current 8.4 series release 8.4.16, as you're missing several *years* worth of bug fixes and tweaks.

The real problem here is that you're using `max` on an expression, not a simple value, and there's no functional index for that expression.

You could try creating an index on the expression `kuupaev||kellaaeg` ... but I suspect you have data model problems, and that there's a better solution by fixing your data model.

It looks like `kuupaev` is kuupäev, or date, and kellaaeg might be time. If so: never use the concatenation (`||`) operator for combining dates and times; use interval addition, eg `kuupaev + kellaaeg`.  Instead of `char` you should be using the data type `time` or `interval` with a `CHECK` constraint for `kellaaeg`, depending on what it means and whether it's limited to 24 hours or not. Or, better still, use a single field of type `timestamp` (for local time) or `timestamp with time zone` (for global time) to store the combined date and time.

If you do this, you can create a simple index on the combined column that replaces both `kellaaeg` and `kuupaev` and use that for `min` and `max` among other things. If you need just the date part or just the time part for some things, use the `date_trunc`, `extract` and `date_part` functions; see the documentation.

See [this earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14855450/398670) for another example of where separate `date` and `time` columns are a bad idea.

You should still plan an upgrade to 9.2. The upgrade path from 8.4 to 9.2 isn't too rough, you really just have to watch out for the setting of `standard_conforming_strings` on by default and the change of `bytea_output` from `escape` to `hex`. Both can be set back to the 8.4 defaults during transition and porting work. 8.4 won't be supported for much longer.

Comment: thank you, `create index algsa_kuupaev_kellaaeg_idx on algsa ((kuupaev||kellaaeg))` solves the issue

Answer (score 3):

My first instinct would be to try an index:

```
 create index algsa_laonr_kuupaev_kellaaeg_idx
 on ALGSA (laonr asc, (kuupaev||kellaaeg) desc)
```

... and try the query as:

```
 SELECT kuupaev||kellaaeg as res
 from ALGSA 
 where laonr=1 and
       kuupaev||kellaaeg <= '9999-12-3123 59'
 order by
       laonr asc,
       kuupaev||kellaaeg desc
 limit 1
```

Comment: Thank you. I added `create index algsa_kuupaev_kellaaeg_idx on algsa ((kuupaev||kellaaeg))` . This makes existing query fast.

Comment: @Andrus While that'll resolve this particular issue, your data design would still benefit from improvement. Unify the date and time parts into a timestamp. +1 short and simple answer though.