# How to speed up max(...) query

Tags: mysql, sql, spring-data-jpa

I have a slow query I'm trying to speed up:

```
 @Query("select max(t.timestamp) from TradeDbo t where t.currencyPair.id = :currencyPairId") 
 Date findMaxTimestamp(@Param("currencyPairId") Long currencyPairId);
```

The entity is defined by:

```
@Entity()
@Table(name = "Trade",
    indexes =  {  @Index(name = "idx_timestamp_currencypairid", 
      columnList = "timestamp,currency_pair_id")}) 
public class TradeDbo extends Auditable<String> {
  @Id @GeneratedValue   
  @Getter private Long id;

  @Version
  private long version;

  @JoinColumn(name = "currency_pair_id")
  @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER) 
  @Getter private CurrencyPairDbo currencyPair;

  @Column(name = "timestamp")
  @Convert(converter = DateConverter.class)
  @Getter private Date timestamp;
...
```

and, as you can see, I've defined an index on the timestamp/currencypairid, (see [how to speed up max() query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14954641/how-to-speed-up-max-query)) which I thought would have made max(timestamp) just a read of the last page of the btree, but it's still taking as long as it did before adding the index.

Comment: I'm not familiar with spring; but in pure MySQL, the index you'd want would be `currency_pair_id, timestamp` (order matters).

Comment: @Uueerdo Ah!  I'll try that.  Why does the order matter?  (updt:  I see scaisEdge has answered that below...)

Comment: "Why does the order matter?" Because `WHERE` is executed before `SELECT` simply said.. The index column order needs to be in query execution order.. More explained here "How MySQL Uses Indexes" https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-indexes.html  and "Multiple-Column Indexes" https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do your query as

```
"select max(t.timestamp) from TradeDbo t where t.currencyPair_id = :currencyPairId"
```

Your composite index is not usefult for you performance  you should change the column sequence

```
columnList = "currency_pair_id,timestamp"
```

using first the column involved  in where condition  ..

the index  content build using the columns  is used  reading for left to right

Comment: Perfect, thanks for that. Query time reduced from ~25 secs to 5mS.  NB: The query has to be "t.currencyPair.id" as this is HQL